# how to find out the port number for nodejs in openshift (django project)?

Tags: django, node.js, openshift

I create a web app using django in openshift. I want to add nodejs backend to my project. I don't know the port number used for nodejs in openshift django app.when I run this script got error :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer().listen(3000);
```

i get this error :

```
events.js:48
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
    at Array.0 (net.js:756:28)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

my environment in openshift doesn't has `$OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT` variable how can I use a port for node.js in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on [this](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/nodejs-example/blob/master/server.js) example)

```
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;
http.createServer().listen(port);
```

Comment: this might help you https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/nodejs-error-listen-eacces

Answer (score 0):

You only have one publicly accessible port to bind to, and that is 8080.  So you can't bind to it with both django and nodejs.  You would need to write your whole application in one language that supports parsing out http and websocket connections (node and java both do this) and then just bind the whole thing to port 8080.  You could also run your applications on two different gears.